# How to prove $E(Y|X)=E(Y),a.s.$ formally if $X,Y$ are independent?

Tags: probability-theory

The question is from **A First Look at Rigorous Probability Theory** 13.4.9

> Let $X,Y$ be two random variable in a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbf{P})$. Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Show that $E(Y|X)=E(Y),w.p. 1$

I read several books which stated this as a property other than proving it. I understand that $E(Y|X)$ is $\sigma(X)$-measurable. However, I have no idea how to start this. What exactly $E(Y|X)=?$ How to prove this?

Comment: Possible dublicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2572175/proving-seemingly-obvious-equations-with-measure-theory/2572940#2572940

Comment: The OP from that question asks many things at the same time, but the thing that is interesting to you is the proof of 1a.

Comment: Remind us of the definition of $E(Y|X)$ used by your book?  Can't you use Fubini's theorem?